# lodash - truncate function returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lodash [_.truncate](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#truncate) function returns a wrong result with the following snippet where a long HTML string is used in the `omission` parameter.

I wonder if there is something I am not doing correctly or if the problem lays in the library itself.

```js
var string = "In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content. Replacing the actual content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced."
    
var omission = '<span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-content="In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content. Replacing the actual content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.">&nbsp<a href="javascript:void(0)">[...]</a></span>'
    
var truncated = _.truncate(string, {length: 150, separator: /,? +/, omission: omission});

console.log(truncated)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Output contains only the omission variable, not the first 150 chars of the string

**Expected output:**

```
'In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on<span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-content="In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content. Replacing the actual content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced.">&nbsp<a href="javascript:void(0)">[...]</a></span>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rule keep it simple.

You are trying to get one thing (the omission indicator) to do two things.

1. Indicate an omission
2. Be a clickable element

To make it simpler hide the omission indicator first of all and then add the clickable element if `str.length` is over 150 characters.

```
var stringLimit = 150;

var str = "In publishing and graphic design, lorem ipsum is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the visual form of a document without relying on meaningful content. Replacing the actual content with placeholder text allows designers to design the form of the content before the content itself has been produced."

var popoverToggle = '';
if (str.length > stringLimit) {
  popoverToggle = '<span data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" data-content="'+ str +'">&nbsp<a href="javascript:void(0)">[...]</a></span>';
}

var truncated = _.truncate(str, {length: stringLimit, separator: /,? +/, omission: ''});

console.log(truncated + popoverToggle);
document.write(truncated + popoverToggle);
```

See my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/altescape/pen/WzBLYj?editors=0011)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's fair to say it's a problem with the library. From what I can tell, the `omission` part returns a string, so if you have a string that's 100 chars long and you want to truncate on 50, but the omission string is 200, then it kind of defeats the purpose, even though what you're trying to do is replacing it with an HTML element.

Looking at the source code for `_.truncate` here https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.5/lodash.js#L15079, you'll notice that if `options.length` is less than the length of `options.omission`, it'll return `options.omission`.

I tested by changing the value of `omission` to something shorter and it does get returned: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxNVJa?editors=0011.

If I understand what you're trying to do, I wonder if it would make sense to truncate the string first, then append the popover HTML after that, as opposed to using lodash to do it.